# Regular expression to match unescaped special characters only

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that can match only characters not preceded by a special escape sequence in a string.

For instance, in the string `Is ? stranded//?` , I want to be able to replace the `?` which hasn't been escaped with another string, so I can have this result : `**Is Dave stranded?**`

But for the life of me I have not been able to figure out a way. I have only come up with regular expressions that eat all the replaceable characters.

How do you construct a regular expression that matches only characters not preceded by an escape sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Java code:

```
str="Is ? stranded//?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!//)([?])");
m = p.matcher(str);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).replace("?", "Dave"));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String s = sb.toString().replace("//", "");
System.out.println("Output: " + s);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Output: Is Dave stranded?
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch - I particularly found this useful in doing parameterized replacements where tokens where used as placeholders for other strings

Answer (score 5):

Use a negative lookbehind, it's what they were designed to do!

(?<!//)[?]

To break it down:

```
(
    ?<!    #The negative look behind.  It will check that the following slashes do not exist.
    //     #The slashes you are trying to avoid.
)
[\?]       #Your special charactor list.
```

Only if the // cannot be found, it will progress with the rest of the search.

I think in Java it will need to be escaped again as a string something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!//)[\\?]");
```

Comment: What if there's two slashes: `\\?` Then the first slash escapes the second one and the second one doesn't escape the `?`.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about this and have a second simplier solution, avoiding regexs.  The other answers are probably better but I thought I might post it anyway.

```
String input = "Is ? stranded//?"; 
String output = input
    .replace("//?", "a717efbc-84a9-46bf-b1be-8a9fb714fce8")
    .replace("?", "Dave")
    .replace("a717efbc-84a9-46bf-b1be-8a9fb714fce8", "?");
```

Just protect the "//?" by replacing it with something unique (like a guid). Then you know any remaining question marks are fair game.

Comment: I suppose you could write a similar version using regex if you wanted more special charactors.

Answer (score 1):

Use grouping. Here's one example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^/][^/])(\\?)");
        String s = "Is ? stranded//?";
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches)
            s = m.replaceAll("$1XXX").replace("//", "");
        System.out.println(s + " -> " + s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ java Test
Is ? stranded//? -> Is XXX stranded?
```

In this example, I'm:

- first replacing any non-escaped ? with "XXX",
- then, removing the "//" escape sequences.

**EDIT** Use `if (m.matches)` to ensure that you handle non-matching strings properly.

This is just a quick-and-dirty example. You need to flesh it out, obviously, to make it more robust. But it gets the general idea across.

Comment: What would happen if the input string was `? is stranded!`

Comment: Or indead even just a single slash: `Hello David/?`

Comment: Yeah, that's an edge case. I hacked this out without considering those. See my edit.

Comment: I intended this as a quick example on how to build a regular expression matching the required substring, not as a general purpose solution for all input strings. I edited the example to indicate that a real solution should consider those edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Match on a set of characters OTHER than an escape sequence, then a regex special character. You could use an inverted character class (`[^/]`) for the first bit. Special case an unescaped regex character at the front of the string.

Answer (score 0):

try matching:

```
(^|(^.)|(.[^/])|([^/].))[special characters list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String aString = "Is ? stranded//?";

String regex = "(?<!//)[^a-z^A-Z^\\s^/]";
System.out.println(aString.replaceAll(regex, "Dave"));
```

The part of the regular expression `[^a-z^A-Z^\\s^/]` matches non-alphanumeric, whitespace or non-forward slash charaters.

The `(?<!//)` part does a negative lookbehind - see [docco here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) for more info

This gives the output `Is Dave stranded//?`

Answer (score 0):

I used this one:

```
((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*[ESCAPABLE CHARACTERS HERE])
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zH1zO3/4