# Regular Expression to Match Unescaped Characters Only

Tags: regex, swift

Okay, so I'm trying to use a regular expression to match instances of a character only if it hasn't been escaped (with a backslash) and decided to use the a negative look-behind like so:

```
(?<!\\)[*]
```

This succeeds and fails as expected with strings such as `foo*` and `foo\*` respectively.

However, it doesn't work for strings such as `foo\\*`, i.e - where the special character is preceded by a back-slash escaping another back-slash (an escape sequence that is itself escaped).

Is it possible to use a negative look-behind (or some other technique) to skip special characters only if they are preceded by an odd number of back-slashes?

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937241/regular-expression-to-match-unescaped-special-characters-only). Also, you didn't tell us the language you're using, and you definitely didn't search for at least 20 seconds to find a solution.

Comment: @AvinashRaj in my case Swift (or more specifically I'm using `NSRegularExpression`), it doesn't seem to be missing any regexp features so I didn't think it needed mentioning. @rac you definitely didn't look for more than 20 seconds at the duplicate you posted, as it doesn't cover my exact case; i.e - its escape sequence can't be used to escape itself.

Comment: @rac It's not duplicate because the other post doesn't ask for this nor has the answer that solves the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found the following solution which works for `NSRegularExpression` but also works in every regexp implementation I've tried that supports negative look-behinds:

```
(?<!\\)(?:(\\\\)*)[*]
```

In this case the second unmatched parenthesis matches any pairs of back-slashes, effectively eliminating them, at which point the negative look-behind can compare any remaining (odd numbered) back-slashes as expected.

Comment: This works, but it cannot match unescaped backslashes - do you know how to extend it to allow that?

Comment: Here, "(.*?(?<!\\)(?:(?:\\\\)*))" matches unescaped backslashes within a string delimited by "

Comment: @DenisGiffeler Backslash escaping and code blocks apply to comments too, I think you meant to post `"(.*?(?<!\\)(?:(?:\\\\\\)*))"`

Answer (score 2):

A lookbehind can not solve this problem. The only way is to match escaped characters first to avoid them and to find unescaped characters:

you can isolate the unescaped character from the result with a capture group:

```
(?:\\.)+|(\*)
```

or with the `\K` (pcre/perl/ruby) feature that removes all on the left from the result:

```
(?:\\.)*\K\*
```

or using backtracking control verbs (pcre/perl) to skip escaped characters:

```
(?:\\.)+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\*
```

The only case you can use a lookbehind is with the .net framework that allows unlimited length lookbehind:

```
(?<!(?:[^\\]|\A)(?:\\\\)*\\)\*
```

or in a more limited way with java:

```
(?<!(?:[^\\]|\A)(?:\\\\){0,1000}\\)\*
```

Comment: Hmm, actually I just tried `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\*)[*]` and this seems to work as expected by effectively eliminating pairs of back-slashes, which can only leave single back-slashes to precede the search pattern (or nothing or a literal). If there's no reason why this isn't valid, I may add it as my own answer.