# Split Down Unescaped Character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a period and backslash escaped string. I would like to split the string using any unescaped periods, but am struggling to come up with a pattern to do so.

```js
const escaped = "two slashes: \\\\.one period: \..line and a dot: \\\.";

// ["two slashes: \\", "one period: .", "line and a dot: \."]
console.log(escaped.split(/* ? */))
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113962/regular-expression-to-match-unescaped-characters-only) `(?<!\\)(?:(\\\\)*)[*]` is close, but `split()` includes capturing groups in the ouput array, which is not what I would like. The solution should be match-only, like [here](https://regex101.com/r/vxxNL6/1):

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\K\.
```

Comment: @anubhava [It pushes capturing groups to the output,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516040/javascript-regex-split-produces-too-many-items) so the pattern can not use them.

Comment: @anubhava That doesn't solve the issue, it needs to match only the period, using capturing groups matches the capturing groups, whether they are non-captured or not.

Comment: try `/(?<!\\)\K\./`

Comment: @medilies [Javascript doesn't have \K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874385/javascript-regex-kkeep-substitution)

Comment: I'm searching for an equivalent [1](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/E8J) [2](https://regex101.com/r/W71bAB/1)

Comment: [This pattern](https://regex101.com/r/vxxNL6/1) works like I want it to, if there's an equivalent than it would answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positive lookbehind solution will work with any JavaScript environment compatible with ECMAScript 2018+ standard:

```js
/(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)\./
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N3CmIq/1).

[image]

The regex matches any `.` char that is immediately preceded with any amount of an even amount of backslashes (i.e. even if there are no backslashes before `.` at all).

With older JavaScript environment, you will need a workaround like `text.match(/(?:\\[^]|[^\\.])+/g)`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N3CmIq/2). This matches any one or more sequences of a a `\` and any single char or any single letter other than a backslash and a dot.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Oh, I did not even notice. OP should actually put the regex try into the question, I will edit it.